# Chrome Tools Auto-breaking

Tags: debugging, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

My Chrome developer tools are great and I love them. I'm experiencing a woe lately though.

Somehow I turned on some sort of *break-on-error* and I don't know how to turn it off. I've looked on Google but it's tough because I don't know the correct term for what's happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the Sources tab, and locate the button at the bottom with two stripes on it.

[image]

Click on this button to switch between the following states:

- [image: Black] "Don't pause on exceptions" (default)
- [image: Blue] "Pause on all exceptions"
- [image: Purple] "Pause on uncaught exceptions"