# jQuery's jquery-1.10.2.min.map is triggering a 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

I'm seeing error messages about a file, `min.map`, being not found:

> GET jQuery's jquery-1.10.2.min.map is triggering a 404 (Not Found)

---

#### Screenshot

[image]

Where is this coming from?

Answer (score 1284, accepted):

If Chrome DevTools is reporting a 404 for a .map file (maybe `jquery-1.10.2.min.map`, `jquery.min.map` or `jquery-2.0.3.min.map`, but can happen with anything) first thing to know is this is only requested when using the DevTools. 
**Your users will not be hitting this 404.**

Now you can fix this or disable the sourcemap functionality.

### Fix: get the files

Next, it's an easy fix. Head to http://jquery.com/download/ and click the **Download the map file** link for your version, and you'll want the uncompressed file downloaded as well.

[image]

Having the map file in place allows you do debug your minified jQuery via the original sources, which will save a lot of time and frustration if you don't like dealing with variable names like `a` and `c`.

More about sourcemaps here: [An Introduction to JavaScript Source Maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/)

### Dodge: disable sourcemaps

Instead of getting the files, you can alternatively disable JavaScript source maps completely for now, in your settings. This is a fine choice if you never plan on debugging JavaScript on this page.
Use the cog icon in the bottom right of the DevTools, to open settings, then:
[image]

Comment: I have two things to add. **1)** Downloading a jQuery map file is not enough, you will also need an uncompressed source code (otherwise you'll see an empty jquery-*.js file while debugging). **2)** If you are loading jQuery from one of the CDNs then all three files (map, compressed and uncompressed source code) are in the same location and you can start debugging right away.

Comment: Im not sure a 404 should be raised for this from DevTools, confuses people it seems. Nevertheless at least I now know how to deal with it. Also @adam-asdf just so you know you are actively encouraged to answer your own question on SO...http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question

Answer (score 281):

You can remove the 404 by removing the line

```
//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery-1.10.2.min.map
```

from the top part of your jQuery file.

The top part of the jQuery file will look like this.

```
/*! jQuery v1.10.2 | (c) 2005, 2013 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license
//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery-1.10.2.min.map
*/
```

Just change that to

```
/*! jQuery v1.10.2 | (c) 2005, 2013 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license */
```

### Purpose of a source map

Basically it's a way to map a combined/minified file back to an unbuilt state. When you build for production, along with minifying and combining your JavaScript files, you generate a source map which holds information about your original files. When you query a certain line and column number in your generated JavaScript you can do a lookup in the source map which returns the original location. Developer tools (currently WebKit nightly builds, Google Chrome, or Firefox 23+) can parse the source map automatically and make it appear as though you're running unminified and uncombined files. 
(Read more on this [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/))

Comment: Required only when you need to debug your minified JS source code. Check 2nd paragraph here for more details http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/

Comment: Wish i had seen this before doing selected answer. This is much easier and SHOULD be primary answer. The op's self answer is good for info, but is definitely secondary as this is the first question that pops up when googling how to g3et rid of this annoyance.

Comment: Editing libraries to get rid of such things is not a good choice. Everytime you update jquery, this line will be there again.

Answer (score 47):

As announced at [jQuery 1.11 and 2.1 Released](http://blog.jquery.com/2014/01/24/jquery-1-11-and-2-1-released/), the source map comment will be removed so the issue will not appear in newer  versions of jQuery.

Here is the official announcement:

> One of the changes we’ve made in this beta is to remove the sourcemap
> comment. Sourcemaps have proven to be a very problematic and puzzling
> thing to developers, generating scores of confused questions on forums
> like StackOverflow and causing users to think jQuery itself was
> broken.

Anyway, if you need to use a source map, it still be available:

> We’ll still be generating and distributing sourcemaps, but you will
> need to add the appropriate sourcemap comment at the end of the
> minified file if the browser does not support manually associating map
> files (currently, none do). If you generate your own jQuery file using
> the custom build process, the sourcemap comment will be present in the
> minified file and the map is generated; you can either leave it in and
> use sourcemaps or edit it out and ignore the map file entirely.

[Here](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/11/15/jquery-1-11-02-1-0-beta-2-released/) you can find more details about the changes.

---

[Here](http://blog.jquery.com/2014/01/24/jquery-1-11-and-2-1-released/) you can find confirmation that with the `jQuery 1.11.0/2.1.0 Released` the source-map comment in the minified file is removed.

Comment: But if it hadn't been for this confusion I would never have looked it up here and known that maps exist. I'd been manually adding spaces to minified files that I wanted to peek into.

Comment: Chrome browser has a button that will pretty format a minified file. Online prettifiers are also available.

Answer (score 43):

1. [Download](http://jquery.com/download/) the map file and the uncompressed version of **jQuery**.
   Put them with the minified version:

   [image: JavaScript]
2. Include minified version into your **HTML**:

   [image: HTML]
3. Check in Google Chrome:

   [image: Google Chrome]
4. Read *[Introduction to JavaScript Source Maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/)*
5. Get familiar with *[Debugging JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging)*

Answer (score 17):

The new versions of jQuery require this file http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.map

The usability of this file is described here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/

**Update:**

*jQuery 1.11.0/2.1.0*

// sourceMappingURL comment **is not included in the compressed file**.

Comment: No, I do not believe jQuery "requires" that file. It is only required if you want to use the source map while debugging in which case both the src file and the map file are needed.

Comment: Hi @styfle, the source map was required in version 1.10.2, but from version 1.11.0/2.1.0 must add it manually, this is because many users were affected by the error that was produced in the browser console

Answer (score 11):

If you want to get source map file different version, you can use this link 
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-x.xx.x.min.map

Instead x.xx.x put your version number.

Note: Some links, which you get on this method, may be broken :)

Answer (score 10):

As I understand the browser, Chrome at least, it doesn't disable the source mapping by default. That means your application's users will trigger this source-mapping request by default.

You can remove the source mapping by deleting the `//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery.min.map` from your JavaScript file.

Answer (score 8):

After following the instructions in the other answers, I needed to strip the version from the map file for this to work for me.

Example: Rename

> jquery-1.9.1.min.map

to

> jquery.min.map

Answer (score 6):

I was presented with the same issue. The cause for me was [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) concatenating my JavaScript file.

I was using a `;\n` as a separator which caused the path to the source map to 404.

So dev tools was looking for `jquery.min.map;` instead of `jquery.min.map`.

I know that isn't the answer to the original question, but I am sure there are others out there with a similar Grunt configuration.

Answer (score 5):

jQuery 1.11.0/2.1.0 the // sourceMappingURL comment is not included in the compressed file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've checked the file is actually present on the server, this could also be caused by your web server restricting which file types are served:

- In Apache this could be done with with the [<FilesMatch> directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#filesmatch) or a [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) if you're using mod_rewrite.
- In IIS you'd need to look to the [Web.config file](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/fileextensions).