# Source map request causes 404 error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, dictionary, http-status-code-404, min

After updating to Chrome 29 I have noticed that the browser try to get jquery.min.map from app root. But request before it was received from assets (small reputation don't let me post screen image for proofing).

Of course, I can switch off source maps in browser settings as at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365315/jquerys-jquery-1-10-2-min-map-is-triggering-a-404-not-found), but maybe there's another true way? And the difference in my case is that the source map was received from assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source maps are only loaded by Chrome when the developer tools are opened, so it shouldn't be an issue for your users.