# Missing .map resource?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've recently started having this problem with all my projects.  When my index page loads which contains a reference to the jquery source file, my console logs this error: `GET http://localhost:3000/js/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.map 500 (Internal Server Error)`.

This doesn't affect my application at all, but it's really annoying to see whenever I open up the console.  Does anyone know where this is coming from?

Edit: Note that I'm not explicitly referencing the .map file, I am just pointing to `<script src="js/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 113, accepted):

jQuery recently started using source maps.

For example, let's look at the minified jQuery 2.0.3 file's first few lines.

```
/*! jQuery v2.0.3 | (c) 2005, 2013 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license
//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery.min.map
*/
```

Excerpt from [Introduction to JavaScript Source Maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/):

> Have you ever found yourself wishing you could keep your client-side
>   code **readable** and more importantly **debuggable** even **after** you've
>   **combined and minified it**, without impacting performance? Well now you
>   can through the magic of source maps.
>
> Basically it's a way to **map a combined/minified file back to an
>   unbuilt state**. When you build for production, along with minifying and
>   combining your JavaScript files, you generate a source map which holds
>   information about your original files. When you query a certain line
>   and column number in your generated JavaScript you can do a **lookup in
>   the source map which returns the original location**. Developer tools
>   (currently WebKit nightly builds, Google Chrome, or Firefox 23+) can
>   parse the source map automatically and **make it appear as though you're
>   running unminified and uncombined files.**

<sup>**emphasis** mine</sup>

It's incredibly useful, and will only download if the user opens dev tools.

#### Solution

Remove the source mapping line, or do nothing.  It isn't really a problem.

---

Side note: your server should return 404, not 500.  It could point to a security problem if this happens in production.

Comment: "... but arguable as to whether it should download for every user..." : Actually, source maps will only be downloaded by users that have their dev tools open and that have the "enable JS source maps" option enabled.

Comment: In Safari browser, Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (angular.min.js.map, line 0): causing issues.

Comment: My question is why only in safari this issue is occurring? Other browsers doesn't show such problem.

Answer (score -13):

I had similar expirience like yours. I have Denwer server. When I loaded my http://new.new local site without using via script src jquery.min.js file at index.php in Chrome I got error 500 jquery.min.map in console. I resolved this problem simply - I disabled extension Wunderlist in Chrome and voila - I never see this error more. Although, No, I found this error again - when Wunderlist have been on again. So, check your extensions and try to disable all of them or some of them or one by one. Good luck!

Comment: its not an exact answer! see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365315/jquerys-jquery-1-10-2-min-map-is-triggering-a-404-not-found)

Comment: This is not an answer actually.

Comment: If you want to ask for an answer maybe you should post your own question because your reply here is considered as answer.