# running exercise 2 from developing backbone.js applications and i am getting 404 errors

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backbone.js

I am running exercise 2 from the book "Developing Backbone.js Applications" and both mongodb and node server.js are up and running, and the application is showing on localhost:4711. However, there are several 404 errors, and uncaught type error. I am attaching a screenshot.

Does anyone have any ideas about this? It seems that the path on one of the files is not being stated correctly.

Thanks.

Regards,
umbregachoong

![backbone errors]http://inetwebdesign.com/backbone-js-errors1.jpg

Comment: It has nothing to do with your Backbone app. It's a Chrome specific error for source map.

Comment: Thanks. Followed the advice here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365315/jquerys-jquery-1-10-2-min-map-is-triggering-a-404-not-found.