# playframework2 jquery error (jquery.min.map)

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

When I launch my minimal play2 application I can see an exception in the js console like:

```
GET http://localhost:9000/assets/javascripts/jquery.min.map 404 (Not Found)
```

Why it happens? Is it known issue. I've seen some [play-tool-projects](https://github.com/jamesward/play-framework-chrome-tools) on github that has this file there. By default I do not have this file in my "javascripts" folder. Should I?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery's jquery-1.10.2.min.map is triggering a 404 (Not Found)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365315/jquerys-jquery-1-10-2-min-map-is-triggering-a-404-not-found)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The source map file maps the minified version of the code against the un-minified version so that you can access the real code while debugging.

The 404 error only appears when using the developer tools. To fix this, just download the correct version of your source map file. Mine for example was:

```
jquery-1.9.0.min.map
```

Then rename it to:

```
jquery.min.map
```

and move it in the javascripts directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try to map of the Assets controller in your conf/routes file.

```
GET /assets/javascripts/jquery.min.map
```

For more information read this documentation

[Working with public assets](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Assets)