# Reference 404 error for a request for the jquery.min.map file

Tags: jquery, http-status-code-404

Out of now where I'm getting this 404 error when browser is requesting the jquery.min.map.

Funny this is that I've never added this file to my solution.

Can anyone explain to me how to get ride of this error?

I have no idea where this file is being referenced since I did not add a reference to this file.

```
Request URL:http://localhost:22773/Scripts/jquery.min.map
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:22773
Referer:http://localhost:22773/Manager/ControlPanel.aspx
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.62 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:4992
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 10 Sep 2013 17:37:40 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?YzpcdXNlcnNcYWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvclxkb2N1bWVudHNcdmlzdWFsIHN0dWRpbyAyMDEyXFByb2plY3RzXEFsdW1DbG91ZFxBbHVtQ2xvdWRcU2NyaXB0c1xqcXVlcnkubWluLm1hcA==?=
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365315/jquerys-jquery-1-10-2-min-map-is-triggering-a-404-not-found ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Source maps are like favicons, a thing that will be loaded by browsers in some circumstances.

Typically, javascript are minified on production servers and debugging javascript on them is difficult.

Source maps are the original versions of minified javascript. It's up to the developers to include them or not on their websites.

In Chrome, you have to activate this functionality for the browser to attempt to download the original non-minified version of a minified script. It is then easier to debug client-side.

Basically, you can't get rid of this error besides providing source maps.

Anyways, see: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/

Answer (score 2):

I just fixed this in my own app.

Files that you copy from a CDN often have the sourcemap line at the bottom. For axios.min.js, it's

//# sourceMappingURL=axios.min.map

Just remove that line and you won't get that error. Better still, use the version they provide for local loading.

I came across this when developing something without reliable internet access, so I needed the local version. Removing that line solved the problem.