# jQuery min v1.10.1 error reading jquery-1.10.1.min.map not found

Tags: jquery

I use `jquery-1.10.1.min.js`, downloaded from http://jquery.com/download/, but when I load my webpage it gives the error `.../jquery-1.10.1.min.map 404 (Not Found)`.

What is wrong? Is there any additional file that needs to be included in the project? Please advise.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365315/jquerys-jquery-1-10-2-min-map-is-triggering-a-404-not-found

Comment: This error is only shown when you open the console, remove the second comment in the jquery source it will fix it //@ sourceMappingURL=jquery-1.10.2.min.map

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the map file for debugging purposes in the console of any modern browser and don't need to include the unminified version of jquery.

If you don't need it, simply remove `sourceMappingURL` in the jquery file, otherwise you can download the map file on [jquery.com](http://jquery.com/download/).