# how to trace where a javascript file request is coming from

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, zurb-foundation

ok, i'm having so many problems with my custom template, it's not even funny ...

it's a custom template for joomla 3.x ...

one problem which i'm trying to figure out is where is the missing javascript request coming from?

i've unpublished all modules, and even uploaded a new template with some alterations ...

but it still persists!

if you view source and click on the supposedly missing file, it shows up fine ... so, why in javascript console in Chrome does it keeps saying it's 404!!!!!

how do you figure how where the request is coming from?

also, I keep seeing this in view source but no idea where it's coming from ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEvent('load', function() {
new JCaption('img.caption');
   });
  </script>
```

EDIT ...

to make it clear what file I'm talking about, it's this one:

```
<script src="/social/services/templates/testingdifferentversion16/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.map.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

if you look at view source, you can access it fine.

if you see the error that it can't find it, hence the 404, the file is indeed missing.

that's why this post was written up, in order to find *where* that request is coming from.

hope this edit clears things up a bit.

EDIT 2 (as per morantis's request)

```
##
# @package      Joomla
# @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2013 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license      GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
# 
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Comment: That looks like code referring to [`jCaption`](http://www.gethifi.com/blog/jcaption-a-jquery-plugin-for-simple-image-captions). http://www.acuit.com.au/Blogs/removing-jcaption-in-joomla2.5.html

Comment: @showdev, the link you gave outlines the same solution which i've implemented for different reasons. I do have this in the template: unset($this->_scripts[JURI::root(true).'/media/system/js/caption.js']);
So, it's weird that it persists. Hm. Honestly, it's not even my primary problem at this point, what I can't figure out is why does it keep saying that js file is missing when it's not.

Comment: I dont see any 404's.  Are you sure you don't just need to clear your console and refresh? :)  I do see errors related to `addEvent`

Comment: I see this as a 404 in Chrome: http://tina.is-a-techie.com/social/services/templates/testingdifferentversion16/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.map -- Does it exist?

Comment: @carter, this is what shows up in Chrome: http://prntscr.com/254yjq

Comment: @showdev, yes! it does. look at view source, and click on that jquery file, and it shows up perfectly fine.

Comment: I can't access that file directly: "404 Not Found".

Comment: @showdev, if you're talking about the error, yeah, it says it can't access that file. but if you look at view sources and click on the same file with same name, it shows up fine. that's why i put out this post because i can't figure out where that request is coming from.

Comment: Hm, just found this regarding map files in Chrome. Might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365315/jquerys-jquery-1-10-2-min-map-is-triggering-a-404-not-found

Comment: @showdev, hey ... clicked on your link and followed the advice of the second answer. it worked, ie, Chrome no longer shows that error. Yay? I mean, yay! (sorry, still down about navigation problem which I've yet to solve) but glad that this is no longer a problem. Since you've technically solved this, if you want credit, make it an answer, and I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: Great! All credit to [Paul Irish](http://stackoverflow.com/users/89484/paul-irish). Post your navigation problem as a new question and we'd be happy to look at it.

Comment: @showdev, thanks again. =) actually, i already wrote a post on this question a few days ago. (right now, I've activated the navigation on the site) let me know if it's not clear) here's the link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918127/mobile-menu-back-is-not-working )

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is a .htaccess file in the root directory and then check if there are mod_rewrite rules in that file.  Many CMS packages use mod_rewrite to handle navigation through the site.  If you are using a program like Filezilla for FTP, then make sure that the program has "show hidden files" set in the options or you may not even see the .htaccess file.  if there is one, post its contents in your question.

I quickly looked and yes, Joomla does use a mod_rewrite to control flow in the website and there are multiple errors that come from this.

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=304&t=346374

This is a link that is not exactly on par with your question, but it does give you the idea of how things can get messed up using .htaccess.  Give me a little more info and we will go from there.

Alright, if you trying to access this [file](http://tina.is-a-techie.com/social/services/templates/testingdifferentversion16/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.map.js) then it will have to be put directly in the address bar.  If you look at the mod_rewrite rules, you will see that if the URL ends in a "/" or does not end in an extension, then it will have "index.php" added to the end of it.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Alright, if you trying to access this file "http://tina.is-a-techie.com/social/services/templates/testingdifferentversion16/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.map.js" then it will have to be put directly in the address bar. If you look at the mod_rewrite rules, you will see that if the URL ends in a "/" or does not end in an extension, then it will have "index.php" added to the end of it.

Does that make sense?

Comment: um, yeah, took a couple of reads of your comment to get what you meant. Technically, showdev solved it via the other link, on whose advice I followed of second answer, and viola, it longer shows up as a 404. But thank you very much for taking the time to help me to troubleshoot it. Much appreciated. =)

Comment: No problem, mod_rewrite can be very useful, but once forgotten it can become a real issue too.

Answer (score 0):

@user2730725 This drove me crazy a while back too!  That file is a .map and is for debugging purposes only.  Turn off the setting that tries to retrieve it by opening Chrome Dev Tools, then Settings and in General there is a checkbox for Enable JS source maps.  Unselect it.  Problem solved.  :)

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer. Technically showdev solved it via another question in which I followed the advice of the second answer. But thank you for taking the time to post an answer. Much appreciated.

Comment: This is unbelievable, it's 6 years later and user273072545345 just solved my problem. Thanks!