# Ruby on Rails with jquery.min.map: Failed to load resource status 406

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a wrap bootstrap theme to style my rails 3.2 app. After including all the stylesheet files and javascript files, I see that some inline editing(which uses javascript and Jquery) is not working as in the demo. I can run the sample pages on my system but after integrating with my rails application, I get the following error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable) http://localhost.lan:3000/assets/jquery-2.0.3.min.map

Although when i look for **http://localhost.lan:3000/assets/jquery-2.0.3.min** in my browser(chrome), it exists. I tried hard but cant figure out what can cause this... Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365315/jquerys-jquery-1-10-2-min-map-is-triggering-a-404-not-found

Answer (score 0):

May be in your application.js file require files are not arranged in correct manner.

You can try :-

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery-1.10.2
//= require jquery-ui.min
//= require_tree .

and in same manner also try to arrange application.css file.