# Chrome insists to download javascript source map files, despite disabled setting, when started from IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, source-maps

I have the same problem as described in [jQuery's jquery-1.10.2.min.map is triggering a 404 (Not Found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365315/jquerys-jquery-1-10-2-min-map-is-triggering-a-404-not-found), except I start Chrome from IntelliJ IDEA debugging session (and use dojo, rather than jquery).

There seems to be no way to instruct Chrome not to download the source map files.

The relevant settings are disabled:

[image]

However, it still attempts to download these source map files. When I load my application outside of the IntelliJ IDEA debugging session, then everything works as expected - source map files are not being downloaded.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Just reported the issue here - http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-120833#