# Webstorm / PHP Storm live Edit and .map Requests

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

I use phpstorm 7 to develop my JavaScript project. Everything works fine, but in the console, I get about 100 lines like this:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost/js/directives/directives.js.map:0
```

I get this message for nearly every javascript file. It tries to load non existing *,js.map files. Can I turn of this logging, or is there any filter option for such cases?

Add screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Open your `directives.min.js` (or whatever the proper file name is) and look for `.map` reference there (should be on very top, in the comments section)

Comment: There is nothing like this.. Here is the full content of the file:


 'use strict';

 /* Directives */
 //
 //
 var directives = angular.module('app.directives', []);


Or look at http://pastebin.com/h07CwGMR for niceer view.

Comment: OK... Can you check all other .js files? I could be wrong here .. but AFAIK browser asks for such .map files only if reference is present (that's why jQuery v1.11 and 2.1 have removed such reference from .min.js files to remove such "spam"). Also -- what browser do you use -- I guess it is Chrome?

Comment: P.S. Have a look at this SO question -- it should have all answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365315/jquerys-jquery-1-10-2-min-map-is-triggering-a-404-not-found

Comment: I have searched for ".map" in all files, but nothing found. I habe now also disabled this source map things in chrome devtools, but in phpstorm I still get the logs.

Comment: I do not know if this can be removed from actual IDE logs -- this messages suggests that you could not: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5501847#5501847 . In any case -- please try **v8 EAP** build and see how it behaves -- http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/03/phpstorm-8-early-access-program-started/ . If nothing helps -- I do have some idea how to filter out/hide such messages via 3rd party plugin (may work or may not -- have not tried it for this purpose)

Comment: P.S. I have tried to reproduce this in both v8 EAP as well as 7.1.3 .. but nothing in PhpStorm console... Can you post a screenshot please (where you see such messages)

Comment: As I have mentioned above: does not happen to me in my **simple** tests. **In any case:** `Settings | Plugins | Browse repository...` -- install **Grep Console plugin**. After restart -- open Grep Console settings (via main Settings .. or via newly appeared button in Console) and add desired pattern to the list -- make sure to put a tick in "Filter out" column (to hide/remove such lines). Should work.