# Asciidoctor.js Live Preview on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I'm trying to use Asciidoctor.js Live Preview on Google Chrome, but isntead of my doc i see

```
Error
TypeError : Cannot read property 'join' of null
```

It also raises an JS error:

```
Denying load of chrome-extension://iaalpfgpbocpdfblpnhhgllgbdbchmia/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.map. 
Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.
```

Probably i need to add sth to manifest.js file, but I have no idea what.

I cannot figure out how to fix this issue. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's an open issue on Github for this: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-chrome-extension/issues/32

Are you using Windows 8.1 ?

The two JS errors are not related:

```
Denying load of chrome-extension://iaalpfgpbocpdfblpnhhgllgbdbchmia/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.map.
```

See [jQuery's jquery-1.10.2.min.map is triggering a 404 (Not Found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365315/jquerys-jquery-1-10-2-min-map-is-triggering-a-404-not-found)

```
Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.
```

The second one is just the consequence of the first one because `jquery-2.0.3.min.map` is not declared in the manifest.

Comment: Yes, i have this problem on Windows 8.1. Is it true that theese two JS errors are irrevelant to my problem?

Comment: This issue is now solved. If you are using version 1.5.5.110 (or greater) of the Chrome extension, it should work fine.