# Qtip2 loads a "jquery.qtip.min.map" from internet and slows down site

Tags: javascript, jquery, cdn, qtip, qtip2

I included **Qtip2** on my site and used the following snippets while the files are hosted **on my own server** as mentioned [here](http://qtip2.com/guides#gettingstarted.static):

```
<!-- jQuery FIRST i.e. before qTip (and all other scripts too usually) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include either the minifed or production version, NOT both!! -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.qtip.js"></script>
```

Though hosted on the same server as the website the script loads the following additional file from the **CDN** of **Qtip2**:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.min.map

This slows down my side extremely:
[image]

**I could not find any information about this. Any idea how to avoid (if not necessary) or replace and host on my own server?**

Comment: Open up the jquery.qtip.js file in a text editor and see if there's a source map URL comment at the end of the file.

Comment: Thanks for the hint looking into the JS file. There wasn't any info. Though I don't want to rely on the hope that removing doesn't produce any errors. I first have to know if the file is necessary. Any idea why I got -1 for this question?

Comment: This still hasn't been fixed. I want to serve the JS files from the CDN and not locally, so commenting out the .min.map isn't an option for me. Is there no solution at the moment?

Comment: Why bother at all? It's not a problem the user sees. You may report this as bug: https://github.com/qTip2/qTip2/issues

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *.map file is a source map. It contains informations like function positions of the non-minified source code of Qtip2. Notice that I used the minified version of it on my webpage.

Source maps help to develop with a postprocessed (e.g. minified) source code without losing the ability to look into the code, for example when errors occur.

The chrome debugger as you can see on the image in my question above downloads it by default. After disabling that function in the debugger settings the file won't be downloaded any longer.

Take a look at this [video](http://youtu.be/-xJl22Kvgjg) for a short information or this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging#source-maps) from Google.

Firefox offers the same feature as you can see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/649271/How-to-Enable-Source-Maps-in-Firefox).

Answer (score 11):

The final line of the Qtip2 script is a line lke this:

`//# sourceMappingURL=http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/.../jquery.qtip.min.map`

Unfortunately the URL currently returns a 404. If you're hosting Qtip2 yourself, you should be able to find and remove that line at the end of the script. Otherwise, don't worry too much because the .map file is only requested when Developer Tools is open. Normal visitors won't download it.

Here's more info on .map files: [jQuery's jquery-1.10.2.min.map is triggering a 404 (Not Found)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18365315/22761)

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded this plugin from here and the problem is solved!

http://qtip2.com/v/2.2.1/