# links are working on codeigniter except the language menu

Tags: php, codeigniter

links and search are not working on my codeigniter website(http://www.mp3volt.com/) except the language menu I have try everything with .htaccess but still not working. When I have click on the links it is not working just display # sign after the url (http://www.mp3volt.com/#), but when it will open if I open it in a new tab.

**dropdown link's sample list code**

```
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>tag/<?php echo encode($value); ?>" class="removehref" onClick="return false;" data-tag="<?php echo encode($value); ?>"><?php echo ucwords($value); ?></a></li>
```

**config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

**.htaccess**

```
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably experiencing a problem with JS, due to you're able of reach the pages writing the url but not by direct click.

After check with Chrome console, you're not loading jquery.min.map, it's throwing a 404 error. I think that if you fix it you'll solve your troubles.

Check this question, I think it had your same problem with js:
[jQuery's jquery-1.10.2.min.map is triggering a 404 (Not Found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365315/jquerys-jquery-1-10-2-min-map-is-triggering-a-404-not-found)

Comment: I have upload the 'jquery.min.js' to my 'js/' directory and setup links on the website. But it is still not work!!

Comment: is your js file rigthly loaded?

Comment: I have download the 'jquery-2.1.1.min.map' and upload it to '/assets/js/' directory also I have tried by renaming it to 'jquery.min.map'   but still get nothing.