# jquery and bootstrap 404 not found

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i have a preety strange problem ( at least for me ). im building at the moment the design of an cms backend and im using a template for it.

the problem that i have is that, before im umploading the html file mailing.html , im getting no error messages in the chrome console, so messages like there is a file not found .

but when im uploading it to my webspace or on a local host im getting the message in the chrome console

```
 GET http://backend.awesom-media.de/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.map 404 (Not Found) js/jquery-1.10.2.min.map:1
```

GET http://backend.awesom-media.de/css/bootstrap.css.map 404 (Not Found) css/bootstrap.css.map:1

but there is no file like this and all others are working perfect.

would be nice if ya could help me there out , here is the link of it http://backend.awesom-media.de/mailing.html

Comment: They're related to source map files and Developer Tools (when the files have been minified). Your end users won't see the 404s (unless they're browsing with Dev tools open). Read more here: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/css-preprocessors and https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery's jquery-1.10.2.min.map is triggering a 404 (Not Found)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365315/jquerys-jquery-1-10-2-min-map-is-triggering-a-404-not-found)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The .map file is being loaded in jquery.min.js from the following line:

`//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery-1.10.2.min.map`

And from the following line in bootstrap.css:

`/*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.css.map */`

Either remove those lines, or upload the map files to your production web server. You can get the map files from the official jQuery or Bootstrap downloads.

Comment: Line 2 of the jquery.min.js, and the last line of bootstrap.css.

Comment: are there any problems maybe later, when i delete them ? just to know for my self

Comment: No, not that I am aware of. It will just make debugging harder. Map files are used by the Chrome debugger to help make sense of the minified CSS/JS code.

Comment: @Peter I checked my entire solution for "bootstrap.css.map" and I found it only in bootstrap.css and its already commented. Still I get 404 in Google Chrome... Any ideas ?

Comment: @Mateusz If it is commented, then that means it will be loaded. Does removing the line from bootstrap.css help?

Comment: @Peter Yes it did :) I don't get why removing and leaving commented is treated differently.