# Mailchimp 404 js file not found

Tags: javascript, http-status-code-404, mailchimp

I added a mailchimp embedded form that I copy and paste directly from mailchimp but I have the following error on the consolelog

```
GET http://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/jquery.min.map 404 (Not Found)
```

Here is the html.erb: (rails)

```
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-081711.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
#mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
</style>

<div class="mc-investors">
  ...
</div>

<script type='text/javascript' src='//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>(function($) {window.fnames = new Array(); window.ftypes = new Array();fnames[1]='FNAME';ftypes[1]='text';fnames[2]='LNAME';ftypes[2]='text';fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';fnames[3]='MMERGE3';ftypes[3]='text';}(jQuery));var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery's jquery-1.10.2.min.map is triggering a 404 (Not Found)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365315/jquerys-jquery-1-10-2-min-map-is-triggering-a-404-not-found)

Comment: You are right, I downloaded the file, put it in my project, removed the call of Jquery. Removed the script from html.

Comment: Hello, can you please tell me what exactly have you removed from the file, I am getting the same error. Thank you

Comment: @Magarusu The file .js that is called, i copied and paste it inside my project, and inside this mc-validate.js I removed the line calling jquery. I hope it helps...

Comment: I copied everything from: http://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js and kept everything starting from the line below: //@ sourceMappingURL=jquery.min.map. The lines from above I think they are jQuery v1.9.0, but I have v 2.1.0 so I think I don't need it. When you say that you removed the live calling jquery, do you mean this line: //@ sourceMappingURL=jquery.min.map ?
Thank you very much for your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery was duplicated as it was already in my application.js and also in the mailchimp template.