# 404 in Chrome, not IE, using asp.net bundles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, bundling-and-minification

The issue is that when the bundles are minified and I look at the Network tab in Chrome I see a 404 for only this url :

`http://localhost:57000/bundles/underscore-min.map`

No such directory exists.

If I remove the reference to underscore.js in the bundle then the 404 is for only this url : 
`http://localhost:57000/bundles/angular-sanitize.min.js.map`

This doesn't happen in IE.  I've moved the order around and there is always one file, and only one, that will generate the 404.

Here's my bundles that generate the issue.

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts")
                            .Include("~/Scripts/angular/angular.js")
                            .Include("~/Scripts/angular/angular-resource.js")
                            .Include("~/Scripts/angular/angular-route.js")
                            .Include("~/Scripts/angular/angular-animate.js")
                            .Include("~/Scripts/angular/angular-touch.js")
                            .Include("~/Scripts/angular/angular-sanitize.js")
                            .Include("~/Scripts/ng-infinite-scroll.js")
                            .Include("~/Scripts/underscore.js")
                            .Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")
                            .Include("~/Scripts/md5.js")
                            .IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/app/", "*.js", true));
```

anyone seen this before?

Comment: You should include the headers that are sent on the request for both browsers.  It is rare for HTTP requests to be treated differently based on browsers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery's jquery-1.10.2.min.map is triggering a 404 (Not Found)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365315/jquerys-jquery-1-10-2-min-map-is-triggering-a-404-not-found)

Comment: Thanks @MikeSmithDev, that was the issue.