# How to find the source of "Denying load of chrome-extension://"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

My Chrome debug console tends to be full of lines like this:

```
Denying load of chrome-extension://ganlifbpkcplnldliibcbegplfmcfigp/scripts/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.map. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.
```

How can I find the source of the complaint?

EDIT For clarity: I don't know what extension is causing this. I have dozens installed. The log is not very helpful.

Comment: Reported bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=446473 See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365315/jquerys-jquery-1-10-2-min-map-is-triggering-a-404-not-found

Comment: Ok, so in this case yes, it's a bug and Rob reported it. I deleted my answer. @RobW you may add an answer linking the bug report to close this question.

Comment: By the way you can easily know which extensions are causing this bug to happen: the extension ID is logged in the console so you can just go to chrome://extensions, enable developer mode and look for that ID (maybe using CTRL+F).

Comment: Ah, thank you. Would you like to convert this comment into an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**As said by [Rob Wu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w), this is a chrome bug, and it has been reported by him [HERE](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=446473)**.

---

By the way, as long as the bug isn't solved, if you are experiencing this issue you'll only need to add the resources that are causing it to your [`"web_accessible_resources"` field](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) in your manifest.

Plus, if you don't know the extension that is causing this, you can find its ID in the console error log, contained in the URL of the resource:

```
chrome-extension://<extension-id>/path/to/some_file.js
```

To identify the extension you can then copy the extension ID and go to the extension page *chrome://extensions*, then enable developer mode checking the box on the top right part of the page and find the ID of the extension either memorizing part of it or pasting it into the search field hitting CTRL+F.

Comment: Thanks. The bit I didn't know was how to find an extension from its ID - "developer mode" indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Avast Bank Mode can stop viewing mp4 and .H264 files. Works in normal Chrome Browser, and not in the Bank Mode.