# Weird request from source map to MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am getting the following error messages in my logging after a recent release:

```
The controller for path '/cspuat/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js.map' was not found or does not implement IController.
```

It would appear that somehow a request is being made to the server from the source map file.

I have tried adding the folling IngoreRoute

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.map/{*pathInfo}");
```

But the error is still happening.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365315/jquerys-jquery-1-10-2-min-map-is-triggering-a-404-not-found