# Source Map Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have not yet found this exact message online yet so i wanted to ask.

What is this trying to tell me:

> Source map error: request failed with status 404 Resource URL: https://example.com/ow_static/plugins/base/js/jquery.min.js Source Map URL: jquery-2.0.3.min.map

The file jquery.min.js is there and it has a 777 permission. So i dont understand why it cant find it.  And what is this part trying to tell me?

> Source Map URL: jquery-2.0.3.min.map

Do i need to update the map to a newer version?  I dont know what the issue is.

Thanks so much
dave :)

Comment: How are you including the map file? Please include the details in the question

Comment: The `jquery-2.0.3.min.map` is the file that is not found.

Comment: I think i finally found it..   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365315/jquerys-jquery-1-10-2-min-map-is-triggering-a-404-not-found